# Mac mini with Core 2 Duo will be good for Xcode?

Tags: xcode, mac-mini

If I have a Mac mini mid 2010 with 4 gb ram and Intel core 2 duo, will it be enough to run Xcode with safari or chrome?

Comment: I've cut out the CPU portion - that's a great stand alone question. Keep in mind - we might already have a dozen questions covering upgrade paths for mini. We might also have a dozen questions on how to understand Xcode requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: Mac mini mid 2010 with 4GB RAM and Intel C2D can open Xcode and Safari/Chrome side by side.

Ram replacement process can be found on [iFixIt.](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Mac+Mini+Mid+2010+RAM+Replacement/3107) if you decide more memory is needed for your workflow.

Answer (score 1):

I write software using Xcode and a 2007 iMac with 4 GB of RAM. The processor is a 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo. The version of Xcode is 7.2.1 and the OS is Yosemite 10.10.5. My Mac is not able to run Sierra, but I do have El Capitan installed in a different partition. I have not yet installed Xcode under El Capitan. My drive is traditional spinning hard disk. (I also have Windows 10 installed with the current free version Visual Studio.)

I often have many Safari, Xcode, Finder, and Terminal windows open simultaneously.

You can not upgrade the processor on your Mac mini, but the memory can be increased to 16 GB of RAM. According to [everymac.com](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-2-duo-2.4-mid-2010-specs.html):

> "Originally, both the official and actual maximum RAM was 8 GB. However, as confirmed by site sponsor OWC, if running OS X 10.7.5 or higher, updated with the latest EFI, and equipped with proper specification memory modules, this model can support up to 16 GB of RAM."